# Django queryset get all data that pass a selected date

Tags: python, django, api

I created an object from a model call `Project` which look like this :

```
[
{
    "name": "project A"
    "start_date": 2019-01-01
    "end_date": 2019-02-15
},
{
    "name": "project B"
    "start_date": 2019-01-15
    "end_date": 2019-02-01
},
{
    "name": "project C"
    "start_date": 2019-02-27
    "end_date": 2019-03-12
},
]
```

if I have a date range selector and I select the date from `2019-01-07` until `2019-02-10`, and my query look like this

```
model_object = Project.objects.all().filter(start_date__gte=(2019-01-07), end_date__lte=(2019-02-10))
```

The result of `model_object` queryset will be  :

```
{
    "name": "project B"
    "start_date": 2019-01-15
    "end_date": 2019-02-01
},
```

What I wanted now is how can I filter the query in such way where I get all the object that is ongoing in between the date `2019-01-07` until `2019-02-10` which mean the result should also include `project A` because its still ongoing from `2019-01-01` until `2019-02-15` even though it started before `2019-01-07`

Any help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but what about filtering just on `end_date`?

Comment: for now I just trying to get all data that is ongoing, which means if even though that object data started before my query start date but if its still ongoing, then get its data as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
import dateutil.parser

model_object = Project.objects.filter(start_date__lte=dateutil.parser.parse('2019-01-07'),  end_date__gte=dateutil.parser.parse('2019-02-10'))
```

Comment: Hi tq for your quick reply, i tried this :

`Project.objects.Project.objects.filter(Q(start_date__gte=(2019-01-07))|Q( end_date__lte=(2019-02-10))).values_list("name", "start_date", "end_date")`

and now it doesn't provide any result at all

Comment: maybe you need convert `start_date` and `end_date` to correct type of your model. Can you show your model `Project`?

Comment: currently both the date field are `DateTimeField()`

Comment: using both `__range` and `__gte` are working but it doesnt provide the result i want

Comment: After re configure my code a little, this worked thanks.

Comment: Apologies, I'm reopening the question, after checking again, it just getting all the data without filter

Comment: different, you used `start_date__gte` and i change it  to `start_date__lte`. Same with `end_date`. Pls re-check again

Comment: if i put `__lte` means I'll only get anything outside the parameter that i needed, i need to get everything that is in the perimeter AND that is ongoing even though it started outside the starting date parameter